# Debug meteorjs application with WebStorm7

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, webstorm

I have WebStorm7 installed on a Windows7 machine.
If I run a meteor project in the Windows7 machine with:

```
>set NODE_OPTIONS=--debug=47977 & meteor
```

it prints:

```
=> Meteor server running on: http://localhost:3000/  
=> debugger listening on port 47977
```

and I can debug with WebStorm7 using the_Node.js Remote debug_ configuration, with *Host: 127.0.0.1* and *Port: 47977*.
If I run a meteor project in a Ubuntu machine (within a Oracle VM VirtualBox, with address 192.168.1.9) with:

```
$ NODE_OPTIONS="--debug=47977" meteor
```

it prints only:

```
=> Meteor server running on: http://localhost:3000/
```

and I cannot debug with WebStorm from the Windows7 machine using the *Node.js Remote debug* configuration, with *Host: 192.168.1.9* and *Port: 47977*.
From the ubuntu machine a `telnet 127.0.0.1 47977` does not work too. It looks like the debugger is not started at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the issue might be related to the fact that node.js debugging is only listening on localhost, so you can't connect to the used port from remote host. The workaround is to use a proxy (see http://delog.wordpress.com/2011/04/08/a-simple-tcp-proxy-in-node-js/, for example)
This proxy can be used as follows:
$: node tcpproxy.js 8585 127.0.0.1 5858
8585 here is the 'exposed' port that webstorm will connect to (you can make this what you wish). You are directing traffic that is coming in on 8585 to 5858 (the local debugging port). Ensure 8585 is open on your firewall if you have one. You have to specify this 'exposed' port in your Remote Debug run configuration as a debug port

Comment: Proxy is working, but Webstorm in Windows7 says again 'connecting to 127.0.0.1:47977' and does not work then. By the way I installed Webstorm on the ubuntu machine and I can debug with. It surprises me that a _remote_ debugger could listen only to a localhost...